# Execute matlab function from IIS 7 + php

Tags: php, matlab, iis, windows-server-2008-r2

I have MATLAB r2013b, IIS 7.5, php 5.6 on Windows Server 2008 and trying to do the following:

```
<?php
...
chdir($matlabScriptsDir);
exec("matlab -r test_func(args) -logfile $logfile", $output);
```

$output shows that process exited with code 0, in the TaskManager I see MATLAB.exe running from the user IUSR, $logfile is created and locked by this process, but the process does nothing – just hangs (there are no issues with running the same command from cmd.exe).

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

using the `-r` option is like entering commands to Matlab's command line, so after the command is executed you still have Matlab running, waiting for your next command. Try instead:

```
matlab -r "test_func(args), exit"
```

So that the Matlab process will end. I suggest you do even more, and wrap it with a `try-catch` (followed by `exit`) so that in case of an error the process will not hang.

Comment: Nope. There is "exit" in the end of function body. Actually I tested this with only 'exit' inside the test_func body.